# Regex Spilt based on multiple delimiters in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of type `"KeyOperatorValue1,Value2,Value2...."`. For e.g = `"version>=5"`, `"lang=en,fr,es"` etc and currently, the possible value for operator field is `"=", "!=", ">", ">=", "<", "<="`, but I don't want it to be limited to them only. Now the problem is given such a string, how can I split into a triplet?

Since, all the operator's string representation are not mutually exclusive(`"="` is a subset of `">="`), I can't use `public string[] Split(string[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)` and the `Regex.Split` doesn't have a variant which takes multiple regex as parameters.

Comment: _but I don't want it to be limited to them only_, what do you mean by that? It would be a good idea to have some validation over the possible operator values.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not mentioned the format of your input I have made certain assumptions..

I have assumed that

- key would always contains alphanumeric characters
- values would always be alphanumeric characters optionally separated by ,
- key-value pair would be separated by non word characters

  ```
  (?<key>\w+)(?<operand>[^\w,]+)(?<value>[\w,]+)
  ```

So this would match a string as operand if its not `,` or any one of `[a-zA-Z\d_]`

---

You can use this code

```
var lst=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(x=>new{
                   key=x.Groups["key"].Value,
                   operand=x.Groups["operand"].Value,
                   value=x.Groups["value"].Value
                   });
```

You can now iterate over lst

```
foreach(var l in lst)
{
    l.key;
    l.operand;
    l.value;
}
```

Comment: The question is, whether you'd want to do some input validation while matching. Your example would accept odd entries such as `abc,,,x!` as well. Also important to note that you'd pick up wrong characters as `operand` as well. Try matching something like `term=(source+target)/2`.

Comment: @Mario OP has asked `how can I split it into a triplet?` its obvious that he wants to extract data from string and not to validate it

Comment: Yes, but you might as well split the wrong characters (see my edited comment).

Comment: Just reread the question. "but I don't want it to be limited to them only"... rather tricky, and possibly no other way considering that.

Comment: @Mario i have edited the answer..I have made certain assumptions to which OP should clarify..

Answer (score 0):

Regex has "or" operator (separators will be included in the result though):

```
Regex.Split(@sourceString, @"(>=)|(<=)|(!=)|(=)|(>)|(<)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use regular expressions to accomplish that. Simply store the operators in an array. Keep the array sorted by the length of the operators. Iterate over the operators and get the position of the operator using `IndexOf()`. Now you can use `Substring()` to extract the key and the values from your input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use branching to provide multiple alternatives. There are multiple possibilities to achieve this, one example would be this:

```
(\w+)([!<>]?=|[<>])(.*)
```

As you can see this expression contains three separate capture groups:

- `(\w+?)`: This will match "word" character (alphanumerical and underscores), as long as the sequence is at least one character long (`+`).
- `([!<>]?=|[<>])`: This expression matches the operators given in your example. The first half (`[!<>]?=`) will match any of the characters inside `[]` (or skip it (`?`)) followed by `=`. The alternative simply matches `<` or `>`.
- `(.*)`: This will match any character (or nothing), whatever follows till the end of the string/line.

So when you match the expression, you'll get a total of 4 (sub) matches:

- **1:** The name of the key.
- **2:** The operator used.
- **3:** The actual value given.

**Edit:**
If you'd like to match other operators as well, you'd have to add them as additional branches in the second matching group:

```
(\w+)([!<>]?=|[<>]|HERE)(.*)
```

Just keep in mind that there's in general no 100% perfect way to match any operator without defining the exact characters that should be considered valid operands (or components of an operand).